# Typescript create new types from user input

Tags: typescript, generics, user-input

In my UI, a user can create a database. They list the columns & their types. I'm having trouble representing this in the type system.

I can do this:

```
interface Database<T> {
    name: string
    data: T[]
}
```

Or further specify the generic:

```
interface Database<DatabaseType> {
    ...
}

type DatabaseType
    = { name: string, surname: string }
    | { time: number, revenue: number };
```

But I can't figure out how to let the user define the "DatabaseType" and have that enforced in the type system. Is this even possible, since Typescript is a compile-time tool?

I've thought about somehow using [fixed-length tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#fixed-length-tuples) but I'm not sure how.

Would love some guidance!

EDIT: Some more info / code

I've represented the user-created database like this:

```
type Column
    = { type: "string", data: string }
    | { type: "number", data: number }
    | { type: "datetime", data: Date }

type Row = Column[]

interface Database {
    name: string
    data: Row[]
}
```

The user chooses a list of `Column` to make the database.

I don't love this because each item in the `data` property can be different. It doesn't enforce the same types for each row.

How can I do this?

Comment: If you have some JavaScript that works, then someone can suggest TypeScript typings that match that.  Users won't be directly interacting with the types you create in TypeScript but that doesn't mean you won't benefit from having your code strongly typed.  Without a self-contained [mcve] though I'm not sure how to give specific advice.

Comment: @jcalz you're right. Added more code & updated.

Comment: like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMLIN4ChnIM5hQBc+hoA5gDQ7IgCuAtifQwEbTW4AmYTyAInEhYAvljABPAA4pUAewA2jEAB4A0sggAPSCC55kAawgS5MNMgC8Rk2bQA+K8g3bd+5HBATkAfkzIwEjVKZC4SVABtNQBdZBFkZggAN2gAbnFpFAAlOQB3dU0dCD0DY1NzdGsyu1RHaxciko8vX2QsiDguORAFCQBBKCg4CRV5JQZVNXtHRJSodIRuglDWJxUAFUK3A2xcEDgGCBICKAoQriE4EgjYgB9kdYiAIguwOCfY12L3UBhoZD6rUBXyaUA6XR63k8EhuvhoGGQEQAcshQDZygDoiQcrk4glaMl-rNoKJ7AAKLisEjrACUVkclPSlLJu1oByOyCeT04oUu1xouAiCMCnJY3NCJAAjHEQsKSE8xecSAAmOLRHmCuWck7isKc94y-wip46pWcp5qjWIrUvXi6xK4wSQMl0kSygLyxUS5CS5UAZjVsQA9EHNIM5FAQgxgHgGEIEAALUQ0rBYIA) maybe?